# Safari will not repaint when using javascript to show / hide elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, macos, safari, repaint

I am trying to make simple DOM changes using jQuery, using show() / hide() and also even using vanilla javascript to try and make the same change.

All is fine in Chrome & Firefox however in Safari 9.1.2 (11601.7.7) no repaint happens, so the dom does not reflow based on the shown / hidden elements.

I have tried the tricks found on google including:

```
sel.style.display='none';
sel.offsetHeight; // no need to store this anywhere, the reference is enough
sel.style.display='';
```

And also the CSS transform trick

```
.repaint {
    animation: repaint 1ms;
    display: block;
}
@keyframes repaint {
    0% { width: 99.999% }
    100% { width: 100% }
}
```

...adding the class repaint on page load.

Neither work. Any tips to forcing Safari to repaint?

1 thing that does work is to select / deselect styles on ANY element in the Dev Tools, resulting in a full repaint of the screen. However trying to force this with Javascript does not seem to work.

Comment: You'll need to create a [mcve], very much preferably using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) to create a **runnable** version right there in the question. Also indicate whether this only affects Safari on a Mac or if iOS is also affected.

Comment: For working on all the browsers including *Safari* you need to add **Browser Prefixes** for your `keyframe` like `@-webkit-keyframes` etc.

Comment: I am using gulp-autoprefixer to ensure that browser prefixes are added.